# Google Maps API 3: NaN While storing lat long co-ordinates in an array?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a set of lat long points which i receive from the database for a specific event. I receive the co-ordinates in the below form:

```
18.9362430987942 72.8269794968548
19.0200931221883 72.8436302614116
19.0547926 72.8406549
```

I need to store this co-ordinates in the array and later push this array in waypoints to draw the route. But when i try to put the values in

```
var geoLatLong=new google.maps.LatLng(linkData);
```

After putting an alert for `geoLatLong`....I get `(Nan,NaN)`..Please Help.

Please find the code that i have tried for the co-ordinates i receieve from the database.

```
load : function(response) 
    {
        for(var i=0;i<response.length;i++)
        {
            if(response[i].linkData!='undefined')
            {
            link=response[i].linkData;
            alert(link);
            var linkValue=link.split(" ");
            var linkData=linkValue[0]+","+linkValue[1];  
            alert("linkdata"+linkData);
            var geoLatLong=new google.maps.LatLng(linkData);
            alert(geoLatLong);
            geoLatLongArray.push(geoLatLong);
            alert(geoLatLongArray);
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass the lat/lon as `string` dataType to `google.maps.LatLng`.  So you need to convert the dataType to **`float`** using [**`parseFloat()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat).

So change the code like

```
var lat = parseFloat(linkValue[0]);  //convert string to float
var lon = parseFloat(linkValue[1]);  //convert string to float
var geoLatLong=new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
```

Now push it to the `geoLatLongArray`.